# Form submit and Ajax at the same time using onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i am sorry if this have been asked before, but i need to send my form data with both the form submit and a ajax call that fires off when clicking submit. The reason why is because the user get's redirected and i want to store det formdata to my database beforehand.

So i try to use the form onsubmit and fire of a javascript function that submits the formdata.
This does not work, the form is sent and no ajax call is made. So i try to take the ajax call out of the function and see if it works then and it does, on page refresh the ajax call is made and my database updated.

Here are som code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="danlevi" onsubmit="return senddata()" action='<?php echo esc_url( get_option( 'shopping_cart_url' ) ); ?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="first" />
  <input type="text" name="last" />
  <input type="text" name="e-mail" />
  <input type="text" name="phone" />
  <input type="text" name="street" />
  <input type="text" name="zip" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

**javaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function senddata() {
    var formdata = jQuery("#danlevi").serialize();
    var decoded = decodeURIComponent(formdata);
    strip = decoded.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "_");
    alert(strip);
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'dev/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/custom/process_address.php',
      data: strip,
    });
  }
});
```

I have no idea why this is not working, what i want is for the page to wait until the ajax call is made, when done, send the form as usual.

If i use return false, it works. I hope that someone can explain what i obviously do wrong, and show me the way of doing this. The alert you see in this code is just for debugging.

Comment: _“The reason why is because the user get's redirected and i want to store det formdata to my database beforehand.”_ – then why don’t you just redirect the user server-side _after_ processing the form data? Submitting the from and an AJAX request “at the same time” will most likely not work, because submitting the form will normally cancel still running AJAX requests. So you would have to wait for the AJAX request to finish before submitting the form.

Comment: This was what i had in mind when writing it, not doing it at the exact same time, but before the redirect. I scratched the code i was working on and wrote it again with tha javaScript Musa provided, it works as intended now so. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait until the ajax completes then submit the form.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      function senddata() {
        var formdata = jQuery("#danlevi").serialize();
        var decoded = decodeURIComponent(formdata);
        strip = decoded.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "_");
        alert(strip);
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'dev/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/custom/process_address.php',
          data: strip,
          complete: function(){
              jQuery("#danlevi").submit(); //submit the form after ajax completes
          }
        });
        return false; //stop the form from initially submitting
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, and i understand it. But when i remove the form from initially submitting it, how does this work with the form's action? When the return false is there ut stays at the page (obviously), but what happens is that the database is getting filled up with hundreds of duplicates of the form data.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment here, i scratched the code and wrote it again using the javaScript you provided, works like a sharm. Answer accepted.

Comment: Isn't it causes to infinite loop of form submitting?